# Adobe Firworks-Line through mapped image

Tags: dictionary, mapping, fireworks

I have a problem with Adobe Fireworks.
I was mapping some stuff via Polygon Slice/Hotspot tool and this white lines appeared cross-image.
Any solutions, how to retouch/delete them? 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX9sN.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the edges of your slices aren't exactly aligned (eg. there's a one pixel gap between them). Can you check for this by zooming in on the slices around the problem areas?

Comment: http://www.renard.sk/sklad/slices.png That's how it look.Do you have any idea how to align them fast? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems there actually, though if you zoom in more or check the pixel positions, you could make sure that way. Is your first image from an html page? Maybe the slices are correct, but aren't aligned right on the page.